# Cannot close Twitter Bootstrap Alert using data dismiss button in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

i have the following div in the devise => sessions

```
<div class="widgettitle">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <%= "<div class=\"flash_error\">#{h alert}</div>".html_safe unless alert.blank? %>
    <%= "<div class=\"flash_notice\">#{h notice}</div>".html_safe unless notice.blank? %>
  </div>
```

but the close button is not working.. anyone can please help ...?

Comment: what is the action of close button?

Comment: i want to hide the bar appeared on error while clicking on close button...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi do you have the appropriate js included?

Assuming you are trying to use twitter bootstrap's alert functionality?

```
!function ($) {

  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;


 /* ALERT CLASS DEFINITION
  * ====================== */

  var dismiss = '[data-dismiss="alert"]'
    , Alert = function (el) {
        $(el).on('click', dismiss, this.close)
      }

  Alert.prototype.close = function (e) {
    var $this = $(this)
      , selector = $this.attr('data-target')
      , $parent

    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') //strip for ie7
    }

    $parent = $(selector)

    e && e.preventDefault()

    $parent.length || ($parent = $this.hasClass('alert') ? $this : $this.parent())

    $parent.trigger(e = $.Event('close'))

    if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) return

    $parent.removeClass('in')

    function removeElement() {
      $parent
        .trigger('closed')
        .remove()
    }

    $.support.transition && $parent.hasClass('fade') ?
      $parent.on($.support.transition.end, removeElement) :
      removeElement()
  }


 /* ALERT PLUGIN DEFINITION
  * ======================= */

  var old = $.fn.alert

  $.fn.alert = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
        , data = $this.data('alert')
      if (!data) $this.data('alert', (data = new Alert(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
    })
  }

  $.fn.alert.Constructor = Alert


 /* ALERT NO CONFLICT
  * ================= */

  $.fn.alert.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.alert = old
    return this
  }


 /* ALERT DATA-API
  * ============== */

  $(document).on('click.alert.data-api', dismiss, Alert.prototype.close)

}(window.jQuery);
```

How are you using twitter bootstrap in your application?

Have you included `//= require bootstrap` in your application.js file? This is required with my preference of using gem bootstrap-sass (relies on gem sass-rails)